# how to override background image in media query for different screen size?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have an email template in that I have used a background image. image size and my template size is 600px (width). I have used class call back-img, I want to override this class for all mobile screen size landscape and portrait. **specially new iPhones**. how do I do this? please help me on this.

---

**media query**

```
<style>

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px)and (max-device-width: 550px) {

    .back-img  {    background: url(https://img.techpowerup.org/200601/cbanners.jpg) repeat-x !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    height: 450px !important;
}
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) {

    .back-img  {    background: url(https://img.techpowerup.org/200601/cbanners.jpg) repeat-x !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    height: 375px !important;
}

    @media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px) {

    .back-img  {    background: url(https://img.techpowerup.org/200601/cbanners.jpg) repeat-x !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    height: 320px !important;
}
</style>
```

---

### **HTML file link below**

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IbaLDv4S0BVWbQIAmTvdGpsSVROoYJWB/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed out the closing curly bracket for each media query. Add a closing curly bracket `}` for each media query and it shall work.

```
<style>

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px)and (max-device-width: 550px) {

    .back-img  {    background: url(https://img.techpowerup.org/200601/cbanners.jpg) repeat-x !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    height: 450px !important;
}}
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) {

    .back-img  {    background: url(https://img.techpowerup.org/200601/cbanners.jpg) repeat-x !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    height: 375px !important;
}}

    @media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px) {

    .back-img  {    background: url(https://img.techpowerup.org/200601/cbanners.jpg) repeat-x !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    height: 320px !important;
}}
</style>
```